# A partial build of jQuery just for $.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, build

Is there a way to obtain or compile a stripped down version of `jQuery`, that just contains the `$.ajax` function, and anything that it depends on?

---

NOTE:

- Background: Wish to create a script which includes just this function in-lined within my own (with proper attributions of course)
- Including the entire jQuery would be overkill for my requirements
- A great example of what I am looking for is Modernizr:

  - http://modernizr.com/download/
  - The download page allows you to select which parts you want, and it will work out the dependencies, and give your a partial build, containing just what you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need jQuery?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4){
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400){
      // Success! run your success function
      resp = this.responseText;
    } else {
      // Error :( run your error function
    }
  }
};

request.send();

request = null;
```

Or a POST:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4){
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400){
      // Success! run your success function
      resp = this.responseText;
    } else {
      // Error :( run your error function
    }
  }
};

request.send(data);

request = null;
```

Taken from [here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#request), a fantastic resource for Vanilla JS alternatives to jQuery. This should work with IE8+.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the you might not need jquery site. This is indeed quite similar to what I am doing at the moment. Just exploring other options...

Comment: i guess the real question is ... why? do you think the jQuery ajax syntax gives you something that you dont have currently or something?